# In MATLAB, how can I automatically find a specific portion of a graph using an equation?

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm new to MATLAB, and I'm plotting a graph which starts off constant, rises, and then oscillates roughly around a constant value. I want to automatically find the x-coordinate for the point where this begins (about 1100 in the figure shown), and I imagine to automate it I need to do something like finding the first point which falls within certain threshold boundaries.

I'm not really sure how to go about that, though; would you be able to help me out?

[image: Plot]

I can provide the data if it helps, but I think I'm probably asking a pretty basic conceptual question with a straightforward answer I just don't know how to find.

Comment: You can start with reading some Mathworks advice on this topic: [Find Array Elements That Meet a Condition](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html)

Answer (score 0):

An obvious answer could be to make up some threshold value, and when the y-value of the graph exceeds this threshold, you know there must have been a jump.

The function that retrieves the x value could look like this:

```
function x = getXofJump(data, threshold)
   base_value = data(1)
   x = 1
   while abs(data(x + 1) - base_value) < threshold && x + 1 < len(data)
      x = x + 1
   end
end
```